# How to add .txt file to shopware5

Tags: shopware, shopware5

https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-5-en/content-and-media/media?category=shopware-5-en/content-and-media

When I try to upload a .txt file to my shopware installation I only get an error saying this format is not supported.

I have a .txt verfication file for a 3rd party system that I need to upload to the system.

How can i, through the gui, add a .txt file to my shopware installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to do a verification for a service like google, right?

In that case, you have to upload the file to your installation, which can't be done via the Shopware Backend.

- You have to use a ftp client like filezilla or winscp (both very
  simple).
- Your hoster should provide you with the needed login data (server, name,
  password)
- From here, you just have to navigate to the part of the installation,
  where you want to upload the file to and, well, just upload it.

I hope I could help you.

Comment: thanks phil! much appreciated